# how to turn on error messages and turn off depending on what the user inputs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, hide

I am trying to validate a form and I want to be able to toggle the error messages off and on when the user inputs a value into the form field. This is what I have so far that is not working:

```
$('#uTagNum').blur(function() {
    var tagNumber=$(this).val();        
    if (tagNumber.length < 9){
        $('#tagErrorMsg').html('<div>Invalid format.Hover over Tag Number column name to see valid formats</div>');
          $('#uTagNum').blur(function() {
        $('#tagErrorMsg').hide();
    });
});
```

If the user puts in "Dgfh578" and it is not 9 characters or digits long then I need the tagErrorMsG to appear below the field. If the user deletes what they typed the the error message will disappear unless again they type less then 9 characters or digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax errors and you probably don't want to use hide(), just clear the HTML for `#tagErrorMsg`. Have a look at this example - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/mqeCj/

```
$('#uTagNum').blur(function () {
    var tagNumber = $(this).val();
    console.log(tagNumber);
    if (tagNumber.length < 9) {
        $('#tagErrorMsg').html('<div>Invalid format.Hover over Tag Number column name to see valid formats</div>');
    } else {
        $('#tagErrorMsg').html('');
    }
});
```

Comment: This did not work for me. And it is probably because my question was not clear. It does show the error if the length of the input is less than 9 and it will clear the error message but I have to back space over the incorrect input and then click outside of the box. What I wanted it to do was clear the error message if the user removed the wrong input and then if they put in the wrong input again it would show the error message again. If they get it right then they can move forward with the form error free.

Comment: Sort of. This is what I ended up doing:
sorry I hit enter before I was ready

Comment: If you can describe exactly what you're looking for I'm sure that we can find the answer for you. Can you add this code, properly formatted, to your original post? This seems to make the erro 'flash' rather than stay visible until fixed.

Comment: I tried adding the code and it would not format. I checked your answer because I did use some of it. The console.log I could not use. I am using IE and I wonder if that is a problem.